# Minimum Value of the function of three variables using Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

Find the minimum value of the function $f(x, y, z)=4x^2+2y^2+z^2$ with the constraint $g(x, y, z)=xy+yz+zx=16$.

I tried and get the following equations 
$8x=\lambda(y+z)$,  $ 4y=\lambda (x+z) $, 
$2z=\lambda(x+y)$. From here how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Now, solve the following system:
$$\frac{8x}{y+z}=\frac{4y}{x+z}=\frac{2z}{x+y}$$ and
$$xy+xz+yz=16.$$
For example, since $\frac{x}{y+z}=\frac{\lambda}{8},$  $\frac{y}{x+z}=\frac{\lambda}{4}$ and  $\frac{z}{x+y}=\frac{\lambda}{2},$ we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{\lambda}{8}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{\lambda}{4}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{\lambda}{2}}=2$$ or
$$\lambda^3+7\lambda^2-32=0,$$ which gives a very ugly answer.